# Losing currentUser when App component refreshes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am currently working on a simple web app using React, `Node.js`, passport-google-oauth20.

For some reason, whenever the application re-mounts, I lose the currentUser state. It's as if req.user is just lost.

The way it works is I first fetch the current user when the application mounts and set this.state.currentUser to the results. The issue is when the page refreshes. The component re-mounts and I lose the user. I tried logging the user and receive null.

Hopefully I explained this well enough... here is the code:

**App component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import List from './List';
import ListForm from './ListForm';
import * as helpers from '../helpers';

class App extends React.Component{
  state = {
    currentUser: '',
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    helpers.fetchUser()
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          currentUser: data
        });
      });
  }

  onSubmit = (id, item) => {
    helpers.addItem(id, item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <List
          currentUser={this.state.currentUser}
          onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

**Helpers:**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchUser = async () => {
  const resp = await axios.get('/api/current_user');

  return resp.data;
}

export const addItem =  (id, newItem) => {
  axios.post("/api/" + id + "/addItem", newItem);
}
```